# float object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, definition

I'm using Jupyter notebook on VScode.
And I have python script with .py having some definition.

The python script include one definition I need,

```
def pressure2depth (P, L, Del):
    # calculate depth from pressure sensor
    # pressure (P) : in dbar
    # latitude (L) : degree
    # Geopotential anomaly (Del) : dyn meteres
    X = math.sin(L / 57.29578)*math.sin(L / 57.29578)
    GR = 9.780318 * (1.0 + (5.2788*(10**-3) + (2.36*(10**-5)) * X) * X) + (1.092*(10**-6)) * P
    DepthTerm = ((( (-1.82*(10**(-15))) * P + 2.279*(10**(-10))) * P - 2.2512*(10**(-5)) ) * P + 9.72659) * P
    DEPTH = DepthTerm / GR + Del / 9.8
    return DEPTH
```

However, when I import this function into Jupiter notebook environment and use it, it returns below error.

```
float object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int.
```

But I copy and paste the definition on Jupyter notebook and run it, it works without error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://tio.run/##bZExb4MwFIR3fsWTutiEOGBEgEjdUqVDBlRlyOqGlwYJbGTMkF9PbYfQViqDZb377s7G/d3clEynqel6pQ10wtyCoMYr9BqHYdTIa@zNDUgVwTGCPbZ0F4D9XuAi2svYCoPwQK5adYsNBpSD0jO6TElFYQeNhPpTPEUb0ZixtuLRiTV@acRZO6DqlUFpGtGCkKoT7R2IO4Uj7xI6NGjDPX6GV38BNjSSHGEDWc54meUFDf8fe9fhw9pKlhdxmhQQAklYDCsgGeN5UYQkicNwnVI34izdzoOMUsue52XlXSWfxa0XKx@/d//mhLqzLYQQIOuEFTNo9zbHszaC28JyEeKnsHZCliwW1/y02GPzbVb@anurTu@26ad14y64cg9ntyUrPKbRjFo@6CDodSMN@fvgJImAR5BSOk3f "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: What values are you passing as `P`, `L`, and `Del`?

Comment: *How* are you using it?

Comment: @Forklift17 P is Float, L is integer, and Del can be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values your passing aren't in the right format.

```
pressure2depth(2123, 234,324) # int or float are passed here
```

Comment: I think the function itself is not the problem, as it worked smoothly when I apply it in the Jupyter notebook

Comment: The values you are passing when calling the function they are the problem. There are no problems with the function itself.